# ListViewWebPart showing ListView Threshold error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, list-view-threshold

On a web part page, I have a Text filter web part that is attached to List web part on a column that is indexed.

This text filter has a default value as blank and the list web part is also blank when the page loads. The issue is when the list has more than 5000 items, it breaks & shows the LVT error.

I already created a filter on status and cannot create more filters as the users have to see all items for the given status. I was under the impression that the blank default value from the text filter should help this ListView web part overcome LVT error.

Any suggestions how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a workaround of this issue. I used jquery data table and filtering it based on text filter value and looks like it resolved my issue.